# Error variable matlab

Tags: matlab

Tengo un problema y es que al hacer una funcion en matlab que calcule una derivada al declarar las variables de entrada que en este caso son dos , pues sale que no lo reconoce dicho error es el siguiente:
Unrecognized function or variable 'posicions'.

No entiendo lo que esta pasando si alguien me puede ayudar a entender lo que sucede se lo agradeceria mucho.

```
function yd=derivada(posicions,h)
posicions=importdata("pos5.mat");

h=1;

y=diff(pos1)/h;


end
```

Comment: Estás llamando a `posicions` en tu función `derivada` antes de cargar los datos de tu `.mat`

Answer (score 0):

Deberías cargar los datos fuera de la función y definir la variable `pos1`. Algo como el siguiente código debería funcionar:

````matlab
posicions = importdata("pos5.mat");
h         = 1;

yd = derivada(posicions,h);

function yd = derivada(posicions,h)
    yd = diff(posicions)/h;
end
```
````

Answer (score 0):

La verdad no se entiende, declaras la variable **posicions** como entrada pero una línea mas abajo la vuelves a declarar y luego la variable **pos1** nunca la declaras.